# How to reshape 128 d vector of image in python

Tags: python, opencv, vector

I am trying to calculate the `euclidean distance` between two images. For this I am first getting the `128d` array of the image and then using `cv2.norm()` to get the distance. Below is the code:

```
embedder = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTorch(<model_path>)
embedder.setInput(faceBlob)
unknown_vector = embedder.forward()

###
# SOME CODE
###

for i in range(len(known_embeddings["embeddings"])):
    known_vector = known_embeddings["embeddings"][i]
    distance = cv2.norm(unknown_vector, known_vector)
```

but above `cv2.norm()` is giving below error:

`cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\norm.cpp:1018: error: 
(-215:Assertion failed) _src1.sameSize(_src2) && _src1.type() == _src2.type() in function 'cv::norm'`

I printed the `known_vector` and `unknown_vector` and it looks like below:

```
known_vector = [ 0.05413035  0.0257974   0.00822693 -0.02118884 -0.00418675  0.21330039
                 0.04995908  0.08850633 -0.10475695  0.04271172  0.08244997  0.11823266
                 0.05605    -0.26287156 -0.03104441 -0.11828042 -0.10454978  0.08653253
                 0.05605    -0.26287156 -0.03104441 -0.11828042 -0.10454978........... ]

unknow_vector = [[ 0.0166864   0.14611466 -0.06341252 -0.017478    0.04083985  0.28554845
                   0.03665403 -0.03293686 -0.05170902  0.07699523  0.06401276 -0.03113891
                   0.05892153 -0.16073132  0.04638063 -0.01014538 -0.07338376  0.07749851
                   0.02471998 -0.10915973  0.16763256 -0.02218471 -0.06936902........... ]]
```

So from above it looks like they different in shape. How can I convert the `unknown_vector` to match the shape of `known_vector`. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use loops where they are unnecessary. Use vectorized operations whenever possible.

Furthermore, I'm not sure why are you even using `opencv`, `pytorch` alone is sufficient for this task I think (if not, please clarify in the comment please), see below:

```
import torch

embedding = torch.nn.Embedding(1000, 50)
example_vector = torch.randn(50)

# Broadcast to (1000, 50) automatically, result is of shape 1000
distances = torch.norm(example_vector.reshape(1, -1) - embedding.weight, dim=1)
```

`distances` contain distances of your `example_vector` to each embedding, you can take `torch.max` from it or `min` or whatever else you want.